# Rails / ransack scope to return one parent row for multiple child rows with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I'm using rails (5.2.4.3), ransack, and postgres with the following simplified db schema:

```
Buildings
- id

BuildingSegments
- id
- building_id
- name
```

Multiple building segments can belong to one building, but a building can also have 0 building segments. There are about 8 mln buildings and 10 mln building segments in my database.

I'm trying to create two queries/scopes, that can also be chained:

1. returns all buildings that have *no building segments* with any of the provided ID's. I am trying to fit this into a scope like so: `Building.without_building_segments([1, 2])`. So this can return a building without any building segments, or with n building segments of which none have the id 1 or 2.
2. returns all buildings which have at least one building segment per provided ID. A scope like so: `Building.with_building_segments([1, 2])`. So this can return only buildings that have buildings with at least two building segments, of which one has id 1 and the other id 2.

I have attempted using a variety of joins, ransack predicates and subqueries, but to no avail.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So the gist here is that you will want to use some ransackable scopes. Basically these are just regular scopes that you make ransack aware of.

```
class Building < ActiveRecord
  # A set of ransackable scopes.
  #https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/other-notes/#using-scopesclass-methods
  # @param [Object] auth_object Auth object from Ransack/Devise
  # @return [Array] An array of scopes that are class methods.
  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    %i(without_building_segments with_building_segments)
  end

  # Scope to only get buildings without segments.
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  def self.without_building_segments
    includes(:building_segments).where(building_segments: { id: nil })
  end

  # Scope to only get buildings with segments of ids
  # @param [Array] ids array of building segment ids
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  def self.with_building_segments(ids)
    includes(:building_segments).where(building_segments: { id: ids })
  end
end
```

```
Building.ransack({ without_building_segments: true })
# => Building without any segments

Building.ransack({ with_building_segments: [1,2] })
# => Buildings that have segments of 1 and 2
```